# Why am I getting inconsistent results with conditional SET NOCOUNT ON in stored procedure called by WebSphere Message Broker?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, messagebroker

I'm writing some flows for IBM WebSphere Message Broker which call stored procedures on a remote Microsoft SQL Server database. My problem is that I'm sometimes getting the resultset which should be returned and sometimes not getting anything.

The lines in the stored procedure which seem to be causing the trouble are:

```
IF (@noCountInd > 0)
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

When I call the stored procedure from a database node in the Message Broker it returns a resultset on the first call then nothing on subsequent calls. If the `SET NOCOUNT ON` is unconditional it works every time. It works every time even with the above condition if called through the SQL Server Management Studio command line.

It also seems as if when enough time has passed between calls for the Message Broker to close its database connection then the next call with a new connection will succeed.

Here's my pared down code to produce this problem:

Stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.pTestConditionalNoCount
    @noCountInd bit = 0
AS

IF (@noCountInd > 0)
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT 'Success' AS RESULT;

RETURN 0;
```

ESQL in database node

```
CREATE DATABASE MODULE testConditionalNoCount
    CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
    BEGIN
        CALL pTestConditionalNoCount(TRUE,
            Environment.Variables.testConditionalNoCount.Results.Row[])
            IN Database.{'DATABASE_NAME'}.{'dbo'};      
        RETURN TRUE;
    END;

END MODULE;

CREATE PROCEDURE pTestConditionalNoCount(IN testNoCountInd BOOLEAN)
    LANGUAGE DATABASE
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
    EXTERNAL NAME pTestConditionalNoCount;
```

Output from trace node

```
Environment: ( ['MQROOT' : 0x29692478]
  (0x01000000:Name):Variables = (
    (0x01000000:Name):testConditionalNoCount = (
      (0x01000000:Name):Results = (
        (0x01000000:Name):Row = (
          (0x03000000:NameValue):RESULT = 'Success' (CHARACTER)
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
Environment: ( ['MQROOT' : 0x29692478]
  (0x01000000:Name):Variables = (
    (0x01000000:Name):testConditionalNoCount = (
      (0x01000000:Name):Results = 
    )
  )
)
Environment: ( ['MQROOT' : 0x29692478]
  (0x01000000:Name):Variables = (
    (0x01000000:Name):testConditionalNoCount = (
      (0x01000000:Name):Results = 
    )
  )
)
```

The version of SQL Server is Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5324.00 (X64) and message broker is IBM WebSphere Message Broker 8.0.0.2.

Anyone have any idea what is going on here?

**Update**

I ran an ODBC trace and it shows two resultsets being returned in the failure case. The first is empty and the second is the resultset I'm expecting.

There seems to be no difference in the way the procedure is called. A SQLExecute is logged for each call then a SQLNumResultCols which returns 1 if it worked and 0 if it didn't.

Comment: SET NOCOUNT ON is good only for the life of the stored procedure.  The setting reverts back to the original session setting once the stored procedure completes.  I suspect an issue with the way the row count messages are beging (mis)handled at the application or API layer but I don't know anything about WebSphere Message Broker.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is related to the caching of the stored procedure objects which is why when you let the connection idle out you see the call work again.

Might be worth examining an ODBC trace of 2 subsequent calls and see if there is any difference between the 2 executions (other than no results of course).